# AppEngine Flex Deployment Failed - flex_await_healthy ... /bin/sh: gunicorn: not found

Tags: docker, google-cloud-platform, app-engine-flexible

I tried to build AppEngine Flex instance using custom-runtime, contains

- Python 3.11
- Firefox

so, while running `pip` for installing the dependencies got into a warning that I am running `pip`as root, which is not recommended by pip maintainers even inside a container AFAIK.

so, in order to solve it I made changes to Dockerfile. Added a normal user and granted permissions to the files and created a virtualenv to install the dependencies.

After that, when I tried to run the service locally, the container  is working fine, but when I pushed the same to AppEngine Flex environment it got failed showing following error:

```
ERROR: (gcloud.app.deploy) Error Response: [9] An internal error occurred while processing task /app-engine-flex/flex_await_healthy/flex_await_healthy>2023-12-29T14:42:11.900Z145758.jc.2: /bin/sh: gunicorn: not found
```

I tried setting the entrypoint in `app.yaml` file with full path to `gunicorn` inside virtualenv. This also failed to deploy.

After, installed `gunicorn` into the system python package. This also failed.

Installing the python dependencies as system packages will resolve the issue. but should I stick with virtualenv or ignore the pip's warning with the flag ?

#### Dockerfile

```
FROM python:3.11.7-alpine

RUN apk update
RUN apk add firefox
RUN adduser -h /app -g "" -D appuser
USER appuser
WORKDIR /app
ADD --chown=appuser ./app/requirements.txt /app
RUN python -m venv venv
ENV PATH="/app/venv/bin:$PATH"
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
ADD --chown=appuser ./app /app/
EXPOSE 8080
ENTRYPOINT /app/venv/bin/gunicorn -b :$PORT main:app
```

#### UPDATE:

The error is appearing now regardless of configuration. I have removed virtualenv usage. And reverted the app.yaml and Dockerfile to last successful state, but it got failed showing the same error.

Comment: Is the deployment environment overriding the image's entrypoint?  A Docker container is already an isolated environment, and you don't necessarily need a virtual environment there; does it help to delete the couple of references to it, and install packages into the "system" Python (but still isolated in the image)?

Comment: We can define the entrypoint in app.yaml file, which I have tried and failed. GCP allow use of any other WSGI servers. So, it shouldn't override it.

Should I use container inside docker is different subject, which I am not good at. ref https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/10556#issuecomment-1014858428

Answer (score 0):

I failed to deploy different configuration that is tested locally running in docker container, all of them stopped at the same error message.

After that, I changed the destination version to a new version name. It got deployed successfully. So, it was confirmed that the problem was not related to configuration. I assume, some kind of caching causing the issue at GCP side.

Finally got deployed to original version after removing the running version, and redeployed it. In between I had directed the traffic to a temporary version (it was not necessary in case of staging environment).